# How to compile java class in different package in command line

Tags: java, package, javac

I have java class in different package on the same classpath and don't know how to compile in command line.

Comment: This is such a common problem that a search for [javac packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javac+packages) in the searchbox in the upper right shows you lots of answers.

Answer (score 1):

`javac -sourcepath /path/to/srcdir -cp /path/to/libraries -d /path/to/outputdir`

Comment: don't forget "path/to/sourcefile" at the end :-)